# gridview dataitem to decimal array

Tags: arrays, gridview, dataitem

`enter code here`Hello I try to convert the dataitem into decimal array, here is my code;

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            for (; i < 9; )
                {


                    if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, headerNames[i])))
                        TotalSales += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, headerNames[i]));
                totals(e.Row.DataItem);
                }

                       }

    }
    public static decimal[] totals(object arr)
    {
        decimal[] res = arr as decimal[];
        decimal[] sRes = res.OfType<decimal>().ToArray();
        return sRes;


    }
```

I can see that the dataitem successfully assigned to arr.
However the line

`decimal[] res = arr as decimal[];` does not assign the arr to res, so the next line gives me an error complaining the value cannot be null.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

While I was waiting for an answer here, I tried and came up with a code that calculates totals in GridView_DataBound event, please comment if there is anything can be better and how to not show the total (0.0) under the columns that do not have decimal values (i.e. string)

```
public static void gridViewTotals1(object sender , EventArgs e)
{
    var grdview = (GridView)sender;
    decimal[,] rowAndColumns = new decimal[grdview.Rows.Count, grdview.Columns.Count];
    decimal n;
    decimal[] totalSalesArray = new decimal[grdview.Columns.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < grdview.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < grdview.Rows.Count; j++)


            if (decimal.TryParse(grdview.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text, out n))
            {
                rowAndColumns[j, i] = Convert.ToDecimal(grdview.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text);
            }

    }
    GridViewRow footerRow = grdview.FooterRow;

    for (int k = 0; k < grdview.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        decimal totalSales = 0;
        for (int l = 0; l < grdview.Rows.Count; l++)
        {
            totalSales += rowAndColumns[l, k];
            totalSalesArray[k] = totalSales;

            footerRow.Cells[k].Text = String.Format("{0:N2}", totalSales);
        }

    }

}
```